# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error when I run my create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to get this to work for some time, but keep getting the below error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch
Category(#70314437722040) expected, got String(#14075760)
```

I have a `Post` model which contains a reference to another `Category` model. I am trying to save a new post with the below form(using haml & simple_form gems):

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.input :category, collection: @category 
  #(defined in new method >>>@category = Category.all.order('title'))
  = f.submit
```

below is my `create` method in my controller:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params) #<<<error here
  @post.save    
end
.
.
private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form like this (I renamed `@category` to `@categories` as well):

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.input :category_id, collection: @categories, label_method: :name, value_method: :id
  = f.submit
```

Also in controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category_id)
end
```

Error in you code was associated with the fact, that by default SimpleForm considers collection as an array of strings. So `:category` parameter was given a `String` value, while it should be `Category`.

Comment: It works! thanks for the explanation.
Just an off question, with the above @categories collection in the form, is what i am doing best practice or would it be better to just pull all my categories directly in my form using `f.input :category_id, Collection.all.order('title').collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ]}` so that I dont have to redefine it in my edit method

Comment: I'm not aware of the best practice. If I was you, I would prefer to define `@categories` in controller, like you already did. It's also fine to use helper methods for this. I dislike the style when you inject select into a form.